# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context- linq join

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am getting this error when I try to join

```
var users = _users.Get();
var userApprovals =
(from approval in _entities.ApprovalEntities
join userDetail in users on approval.UserKey equals userDetail.UserId
 where approval.EmployeeUid == employeeUid
 select new UserApproval
{
Id = approval.Id,
EmployeeUid = approval.EmployeeUid,
UserKey = approval.UserKey,
UserId = approval.UserId,
UserName = userDetail.FirstName + " " + userDetail.LastName
}).ToList();
```

error 
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, 
var userApprovals =

```
(from approval in _entities.ApprovalEntities.ToList()
join userDetail in users on approval.UserKey equals userDetail.UserId
 where approval.EmployeeUid == employeeUid
 select new UserApproval
{
Id = approval.Id,
EmployeeUid = approval.EmployeeUid,
UserKey = approval.UserKey,
UserId = approval.UserId,
UserName = userDetail.FirstName + " " + userDetail.LastName
}).ToList();
```

Comment: So your fix fetches all records from ApprovalEntities table. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my problem was use IEnumerable without using toList() sentence.

Look, this code show "error Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context" error:

```
var query = db.TemplatesDocs.Where(x => x.Id_Template == idTmpl)
        .Join(Utils.DocumentTypes, x => x.Id_Type, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new { tmpDoc = x, type = y } )
        .ToList();
```

Look, this code is fixed the error:

```
var query = db.TemplatesDocs.Where(x => x.Id_Template == idTmpl).ToList()
        .Join(Utils.DocumentTypes, x => x.Id_Type, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new { tmpDoc = x, type = y } )
        .ToList();
```